# How to disable keyboard shortcuts using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver, key

I am using this piece of code the browser to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to print..

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "p");
driver.findElement(By.className("link-box")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

But I want to disable this on my browser.

Comment: if you will disable then how your send keys will press? and function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable keyboard OS shortcuts with Selenium.

Selenium drives the browser, it does not interact with the OS.  If you want to disable OS shortcuts you will need to interact with the OS to do so, Selenium can't interact with the OS.